# Вывод результата MySQL-запроса с помощью PHP - как лучше?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть к примеру таблица:

```
id  | col_1 | col_2
1   |   a   |   c
2   |   d   |   b
3   |   v   |   n
4   |   b   |   h
5   |   b   |   a
... и т.д.
```

Нужно сделать такой вывод:

```
<div> 1, 5 </div> <!-- все id где в col-1 OR в col-2 есть "a" -->
<div> 5, 12 </div> <!-- все id где в col-1 есть "а" AND в col-2 есть "b" OR в col-1 есть "b" AND в col-2 есть "a"  -->
<div> 2, 4, 5 </div> <!-- все id где в col-1 OR в col-2 есть "b" -->
```

Вот  так это делаю я:

```
$div1_q = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE col_1='a' OR col_2='a'");
$div2_q = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE col_1='a' AND col_2='b' OR col_1='b' AND col_2='a'");
$div3_q = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE col_1='b' OR col_2='b'");

$div1 ='';
$div2 ='';
$div3 ='';
while($div1_r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($div1_q)) {
    $div1 .= $div1_r['id'];
}
while($div2_r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($div2_q)) {
    $div2 .= $div2_r['id'];
}
while($div3_r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($div3_q)) {
    $div3 .= $div3_r['id'];
}
```

Кому не составит труда, подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли лучшее решение? Пример запроса и хоть немного php =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать union:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, 
    "(SELECT id, 1 FROM test WHERE col_1='a' OR col_2='a')
        UNION ALL
     (SELECT id, 2 FROM test WHERE col_1='a' AND col_2='b' OR col_1='b' AND col_2='a')
        UNION ALL
     (SELECT id, 3 FROM test WHERE col_1='b' OR col_2='b')");

$div1 = '';
$div2 = '';
$div3 = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    if($row['1'] == 1)
    {
        $div1 .= $row['id'];
    }
    else if($row['1'] == 2)
    {
        $div2 .= $row['id'];
    }
    else if($row['1'] == 3)
    {
        $div3 .= $row['id'];
    }    
}
```

Comment: Пасибо, работает...